# Webapp can't find file in Tomcat but path exists on system

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey

I have a Java web app deployed in Tomcat and I need to read a particular file placed inside the webapp's directory.

The path it tries to read:

```
String path = "C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 7.0\\webapps\\my-server\\config\\myfile.csv";
File file = new File(path);
if(file.exists())
    //read the file...
```

`file.exists()` returns false but I can navigate to that path in Windows Explorer.
Is this some kind of permissions issue?
Any clues as to what might be wrong? I'm very lost.

Comment: why do you change the slashes at the end of the string from back to forward?

Comment: Why don't you read the resource from the classpath instead?

Comment: Use forward slashes on Windows, forget all that escaping nonsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is far from the best way to achieve what you are trying to do. For one thing it is extremely brittle.

You should be using `ServletContext.getResourceAsStream("/config/myfile.csv")`

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd say is to replace your '\' with '\'.

If this doesn't work have a look at the security permissions on the specific folder the CSV is located in.

Add user `everyone` and allow read access.

Additionally, putting a hardcoded path is not the best way to read a file, as you can use java enterprise functions that allow reading files from specific locations (of a deployed war).

Answer (score 0):

try escaping the backslashes like so:

```
String path = "C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 7.0\\webapps\\myserver\\config\\myfile.csv";
```

And I also noticed that you make a wrong reference to 'file'.

```
if(File.exists())
```

Could be that you just copied it wrong :). Else I don't know. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yea those r mostly copy paste errors. It's not the actual code but that's String the path resolves to.

Answer (score -1):

First of all , should not use absolute path, who knows when you deploy it in some other place , the path is going to hold true always ? You can use a relative path as shown.

```
String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
```

It will give your webapp directory,then you can give the path as

```
contextPath+="config\\myfile.csv"
```

Also use `System.getProperty("file.separator");` instead of slashes for platform independence.

Comment: contextPath doesn't return what you think it does.

Comment: @MarkThomas can u tell me what it returns , I thought it always returned the context of the webapp

Comment: It does return the context path but that has no relationship to the file system path. You might have been thinking of getRealPath() but that is an equally poor way of doing things as it not guaranteed to work.